# MapReduce with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a document like this on MongoDB:

```
[
    {
        "option": "My fav food is pizza",
        "person": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John"
        },
        "location": {
            "country": "UK",
            "europe": "N"
        }
    },
    {
        "option": "I love football",
        "person": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jack"
        },
        "location": {
            "country": "UK",
            "europe": "N"
        }
    }
]
```

And I have to obtain something like this, using MapReduce:

```
{
    "country": "UK",
    "value": {
        "count": 2,
        "sentences": [
            "I love football",
            "My fav food is pizza"
        ],
        "people": [
            "Jack",
            "John"
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have to deal with it using MapReduce (map, reduce and finalize) on Javascript and I am a little bit stuck on it.

I can't find any good examples as hard as this...

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

we can write a reducer here to create a new object from the array.

The below code is an illustration of such an implementation

```js
const dataEntity = [
    {
        "option": "My fav food is pizza",
        "person": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John"
        },
        "location": {
            "country": "UK",
            "europe": "N"
        }
    },
    {
        "option": "I love football",
        "person": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jack"
        },
        "location": {
            "country": "UK",
            "europe": "N"
        }
    }
];

let items = 0;
let sentences = [];
let people = [];
const transformedObject = dataEntity.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
    debugger;
    items+=1;
    sentences.push(curr.option);
    people.push(curr.person.name);
    acc["country"]=curr.location.country;
    if(!acc["value"]){
        acc["value"]={};
    }
    acc["value"]["count"] = items;
    acc["value"]["sentences"]=sentences;
    acc["value"]["people"]=people;
    return acc;
},{})

console.log(transformedObject);
```

This is a simple illustration. You can further modify this snippet to fit the requirements.

Cheers.